# what is the regular expression for the below condition?

Tags: regex

```
"VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR.Value"SETTINGSTRUEAPPEND"VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR_LAST.Value"
```

I want to take `"VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR.Value" and "VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR_LAST.Value"`

for this `"VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR["SUM.service.value"].Value"SETTINGSTRUEAPPEND"VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR_LAST.Value"`

I want to take `"VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR["SUM.service.value"].Value"` and `"VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR_LAST.Value"`

currently I am using the below regex but its not working. `(\"(VARS|BDX)[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\[\]\"\"\']*\"(?! (VARS|BDX)))`

Comment: In the below value. i need to take "VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR["SUM.service.value"].Value" "VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR["SUM.service.value"].Value"SETTINGSTRUEAPPEND"VARS.ACT_PUMP‌​_MOTOR_LAST.Value"

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:VARS|BDX)[^"]*
```

You can simply do this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/3

Comment: In the below value. i need to take  "VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR["SUM.service.value"].Value" "VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR["SUM.service.value"].Value"SETTINGSTRUEAPPEND"VARS.ACT_PUMP_MOTOR_LAST.Value"